# How to change colour of selected icon in the BottomNavigation component of React Native Paper?

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-paper

I have the next page that uses `BottomNavigation`:

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  BottomNavigation,
  DefaultTheme,
  Provider as PaperProvider,
} from 'react-native-paper'
import ChatScreen from './presentation/screens/ChatScreen'
import HomeScreen from './presentation/screens/HomeScreen'
import MapScreen from './presentation/screens/MapScreen'
import PostScreen from './presentation/screens/PostScreen'
import ProfileScreen from './presentation/screens/ProfileScreen'

const App = () => {
  const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0)
  const [routes] = React.useState([
    {key: 'home', icon: 'home'},
    {key: 'map', icon: 'compass'},
    {key: 'post', icon: 'plus-box'},
    {key: 'profile', icon: 'account'},
    {key: 'chat', icon: 'forum'},
  ])

  const renderScene = BottomNavigation.SceneMap({
    home: HomeScreen,
    map: MapScreen,
    post: PostScreen,
    profile: ProfileScreen,
    chat: ChatScreen,
  })

  return (
    <PaperProvider theme={lightTheme}>
      <BottomNavigation
        labeled={false}
        navigationState={{index, routes}}
        onIndexChange={setIndex}
        renderScene={renderScene}
      />
    </PaperProvider>
  )
}

export default App
```

This code uses a default icon tint colour from the theme. However, how to use a different colour for every icon?

[image: Screenshots]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may use [react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons) library. Now you can set custom color to icons.

For example:

```
import FontAwesome from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';


{ key: 'home', icon: (props) => <FontAwesome color="pink" {...props} name='home' /> },
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! Although there is a small error: `{...props}` must be passed before `color` attribute. In my case, it will be `<MaterialCommunityIcons {...props} color="pink" name="home" />`